# Trying to implement friends with Rails, getting a No Route Matches [GET] error when I try to route to any controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been searching for an answer for the past few hours and I'm really frustrated, I'm new to Rails so I feel like it is a stupid mistake or I just did something totally wrong. Please help me fix this error. Here is my controller:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :def_user, only: [:create, :accept, :deny, :destroy]

    def index
        @user = current_user
        @friends = @user.friends.paginate :page => params[:page]
        @pending_friends = @user.pending_friends.paginate :page => params[:page]
    end

    def show
    end

    def create
        Friendship.request(@user1, @friend)
        flash[:success] = "Friend request has been sent to #{@user2.screenname}."
        redirect_to user_path(@friend)
    end

    def accept
        Freindship.accept(@user1, @friend)
        flash[:success] = "Friend request from #{@user2.screenname} has been accepted."
        redirect_to friends_path
    end

    def deny
        Friendship.breakup(@user1, @friend)
        flash[:success] = "Friend request from #{@user2.screenname} has been declined."
        redirect_to friends_path
    end

    def destroy
        Friendship.breakup(@user1, @friend)
        flash[:success] = "#{@user2.screenname} has been successfully removed from your friends list."
        redirect_to friends_path
    end

    private

    def def_user
        @user1 = current_user
        @friend = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

and my model:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User'


    def self.request(user, friend)
        unless user == friend or Friendship.exists?(user, friend)
            transaction do
                create(:user => user, :friend => friend, :status => 'pending')
                create(:user => friend, :friend => user, :status => 'requested')
            end
        end
    end

    def self.accept(user, friend)
        transaction do
            accepted_at = Time.now
            accept_one_side(user, friend, accepted_at)
            accept_one_side(friend, user, accepted_at)
        end
    end

    def self.breakup(user, friend)
    transaction do
      destroy(find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend))
      destroy(find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(friend, user))
      end
    end

    private

    def self.accept_one_side(user, friend, accepted_at)
        request = find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user, friend)
        request.status = 'accepted'
        request.accepted_at = accepted_at
        request.save!
    end
end
```

In my routes file I have

```
get 'friends/create', to: 'friendships#create', as: 'add_friend'
```

The line in my views that calls it is this:

```
<%= link_to "Send Friend Request", add_friend_path(current_user, @user), method: :get, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

I have also tried

```
<%= link_to 'Send Friend Request', {:controller => 'friendships', :action => 'create', :id => @user.id}, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
```

Sorry for my noobiness, and thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider to add in `:id` to the route.

```
get 'friends/create/:id', to: 'friendships#create', as: 'add_friend'
```

You trying to get def_user by `params[:id]`, but `id` is not present in the route.

Just a thougths:

That code

```
flash[:success] = "Friend request from #{@user2.screenname} has been accepted."
```

will fail with

```
undefined method `screenname' for nil:NilClass
```

because it's no `@user2` defined.

Also pleae note that CRUD implementation assumes to use different HTTP methods as `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`

So, for creating a friendship `POST` method suits better than `GET`. The same for `deny` and `destroy` actions.

Rails provides convenient resource routes http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have made some changes and it gives me an error I got a few times before, it's "Couldn't find User with 'id'=". I was wondering if I had the line in the views wrong. I'm not sure how to "input" the two users into the controller method. I tried to do it by defining them like add_friend_path(current_user, pending_friend), but the second input is coming out as nil, so I'm doing something wrong. Would you happen to have some idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't pass a user instance itself. just pass it's id with:

Comment: Ok awesome, I fixed most of it :) Thanks for your help. In the end it was:

-putting the right thing between get/post/put

-making sure I had the right variable set up in my controller

-passing in the right number of and the right variable into the line in my views

Comment: Welcome! :) Please mark my answer as right if it was helpful.